# Identify Tesla Model S connector

Tags: connector, identification

Can you help in identifying the connector? It's used for Ethernet signaling.

[image]

Comment: What kind of device is this connector on?

Comment: Tesla Model S central console. I'm pretty sure that this is either Ethernet or USB.

Comment: If USB,there is sure 4 connectors.One will be Vcc,another will be Ground , Differential signal pairs two pins (D+ and D-)

Comment: But what is the type of the connector? I want to make an adapter for it and I have no idea how to order the plug.

Comment: Some "Quadrax" derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a [RosenbergerHSD](https://www.rosenberger.com/en/products/automotive/hsd.php) ([Product Brochure](https://www.rosenberger.com/0_documents/de/specs/auto/hsd.pdf)) connector, variant B in the table below.

[image: RosenbergerHSD]

I have also seen them called [FAKRA connectors](http://offer.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=tesla%20fakra) on alibaba, but it's probably not technically correct, as FAKRA appears to be a type of RF connector.

Comment: Yes, dimensions match. And this definitely is an Ethernet connector.

Comment: Now I'd like to know where I can buy it. But it looks like 3D-printing might be the best bet.

Comment: @Cyberax Check out this page: http://www.rfstreet.com/ch_list.asp?styleid=147&cp_id=2